# Why is didSelectItem not called on my UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, swift

How does selecting an item on a tab bar work?

This my code

```
@IBOutlet var tabBar: UITabBar!
@IBOutlet var item: UITabBarItem!
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 0 {
        print("if this worktap 1")

        let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        vc.setInitialText("Look at this !")
        vc.addURL(NSURL(string: "https://link.com"))
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        // code
    print("if this work tap 2")
    }
}
```

But nothing happens when I tap an item.

Comment: please, don't use tags, it's a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

i fix it by using some code from ViewController

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p609tabBar/ch25p880tabBar/ViewController.swift